# android menu which open a webview or a slide image

Tags: android, webview, onclick

I need to create a menu which opens a webview page or a simple page with images slide.

I'm more proficient in web programming, not so much in programming for Android. So if it is easier to do it in a `WebView` I will use it. I will use the images slide otherwise.

So for now, I need 2 items when I press the menu button of the phone. Upon clicking they should open 2 different links in the app (not in the browser).

I've done only `menu.xml` for now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_howto" android:title="@string/howto"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_howto" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_about" android:title="@string/about"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main `class` you must @override the menu like:-

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and then to make the menu buttons clickable you have to add this after

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
         return true;
        case R.id.loadanotherwebpage:
loadUrl("www.google.com"); 
// inside the menu button you don't need to call Super.loadUrl, LoadUrl its enough 
            return true;
        case R.id.share:
            share(); // here i'm calling the share method !
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

edit : if you want to load the html file from assets file then do this

```
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

hope that what you asking for :)

Comment: maybe yes, but idk, what to import in add to "import android.view.Menu; & import android.view.MenuItem;" ? Cuz my complier gives me errors like:
 cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable activity_main
    [javac] location: class com.worfut.project.R.menu
    [javac]     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

and
cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method loadUrl(java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class com.worfut.project.MainActivity

Comment: ive solved the first error cuz my xml file's name was menu and not activity_main, but i cannot solve the problm about "method loadURl and share". (ive 4 buttons now, ive added exit and share as in the code you give me :>)

Comment: Kosh() and loadUrl are im using them u have to replace them with ur own stuff. Lets say in menu button about us. U should create dialog or a layout. Im just given u an example in above code in how to use the menu. Any way if that helped u pls accept the answer and im around if u needed any more details

Comment: done, but however i use "loadurl" in the webview i have already in my app (in the same file .java). so idk why loadurl dont run.
im now understand how function but if id like to add loadurl idk how to do.
thanks :>

Comment: are you using phongap or no ? if your site is offline base then i recommend you to use phongap .. if loadUrl doesn't work. then please make it like this super.loadUrl("yoursite"); 
and if you are using android webview then tell me and i'll give you an example in how to use it. its easy tho.

Comment: i dont use phonegap but i use webview my app is a webview (ive added a menu).. the name of webview is WorfutWeb